# Error OAuthException: (#200) when inviting to Event

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting the Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200)

when i try to invite people via an App to an event.

My Steps:
1. Getting long lived token with Permissions: create_event create_note publish_actions publish_stream rsvp_event user_events
2. Getting Userids who are friends and not already invited to the event.
3. Split into 50 Persons per Invite and send it.

Code for Inviting:

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array(
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' => "SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND NOT 
(uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = '$eventid'))"));

foreach ($friends as $value) 
{
    if (!isset($allids))
    {
        $allids = $value['uid'];
    }
    else
    {
        $allids .= ',' . $value['uid'];
    }
    $count++;
    $invitedusers++;
    if ($count > 49) 
    {
    //$splitinvite = $facebook->api($eventid . '/invited?users=' . $allids, 'POST');
    unset($allids);
    $count = 0;
    }
}

$facebook->api($eventid . '/invited?users=' . $allids, 'POST');
```

I already seperated the Userids to make sure that they are setted correctly in the format Userid_1,Userid_2,Userid_3
I checked the token with the graph token debugger and all permissions are setted correctly.
Anyone an idea?

Comment: I think i figured out the problem.
I forgot to care about the case if someone blocked event invatations. Does anybody know how i can find out if someone blocked invataions?

Answer (score 0):

One posibility is the following Code. But this works realy slow because it sends a query for each person. 
It takes up 30 Seconds for checking 37 people. Querying 50 people at once as shown above invites over 1000 people in 30 seconds.

**I would appreacheate it if anyone can try to find a better way!!!**
The best way would be filtering the FQL query (if is posible).

Slow working Code:

```
    foreach ($friends as $value) 
    {       
        try
        {
        $splitinvite = $facebook->api($eventid . '/invited?user=' . $value['uid'],'POST'); 
        $count++;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
// Users privacy setting blocked inviting him, has blocked you or has blocked you from inviting 
        }
}
```